# React, Apollo, GraphQL - issue trying to output data from returned query

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm currently following a GraphQL tutorial by netninja on you tube (I'm on lesson #35). The React instructions are a little out of data, so I've had to read the latest docs to get some parts working. However, I'm now stuck on a somewhat straight forward looking issue. I have a query which connects to my graphQL server and retrieves data and I want to output the data. I can output the data object to the console but when i try to access the different pieces of information I get 'undefined' error:

Link to the original code created by the instructor on github:
https://github.com/iamshaunjp/graphql-playlist/blob/lesson-35/client/src/components/BookDetails.js

Here is my query:

```
const getBookQuery = gql`
    query($id: ID){
        book(id: $id) {
            id
            name
            genre
            author {
                id
                name
                age
                books {
                    name
                    id
                }
            }
        }
    }
`;
```

And here is my React code:

```
import { getBookQuery } from '../queries/queries';
import { graphql, useQuery } from "@apollo/client";

const displayBookDetails = (loading, data) =>{
    if(loading){
        return( <p>Loading book details</p> );
    }else{
        return(
            <div>
                <h2>{ data.name }</h2>
                <p>{ data.genre }</p>
                <p>{ data.author.name }</p>
                <p>All books by this author:</p>
                <ul className="other-books">
                    { data.author.books.map(item => {
                        return <li key={item.id}>{ item.name }</li>
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

function BookDetails({ bookid }) {
    const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(getBookQuery, { variables: { id: bookid }});
console.log( bookid );
console.log( data );
    return (
    displayBookDetails(loading, data)
    );
}

export default BookDetails;
```

Thanks in advance.

Update:
Here is the error from the console:

```
[GraphQL error]: Message: Variable "$id" got invalid value { bookid: "60f6cab81c87353e5be8c513" }; ID cannot represent value: { bookid: "60f6cab81c87353e5be8c513" }, Location: [object Object], Path: undefined
```

Update2:
The code which calls BookDetails and passes the bookid

```
import { useQuery  } from "@apollo/client";
import { useState } from "react";
import {getBooks} from '../queries/queries';

//Components
import BookDetails from './BookDetails';

function BookList() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState(null);
  const bookid = '';
  const {loading, error, data} = useQuery(getBooks);
  if (loading) return <p>Loading...</p>;
  if (error) return <p>Error </p>;
  console.log(data);
  console.log('selected:'+selected);
  return (
    <div>
      <ul id="book-list">
        {data.books.map(book => (
          <li key={book.id} onClick={(e) => setSelected(book.id)}>{book.name}</li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <BookDetails bookid={selected}/> {/* <--- Here is where the bookid is passed to bookdetails component */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default BookList;
```

Comment: place `console.log` in `displayBookDetails`, in proper parts/conditions - conditions are for sth - rethink their role in time (rerenderings on change), read apollo docs again

Comment: if `console.log( "bookid: ", bookid );` logs an object (should be a string) then bad `bookid` prop/value passed to `<BookDetails/>` component

Comment: I think you are correct and the way I have passed the bookid is bad. I've added the code which calls the BookDetails component above.

Comment: code looks good ... but nothing about log results, [1st query] data structures, network query body (dev tools), passed props (react dev tools) ... `{selected && <BookDetails ...>}`, ... just call `displayBookDetails()`, instead of `return ( displayBookDetails`

Answer (score 0):

It seems the code that calls / renders `BookDetails` is missing.

And it looks like you are rendering it as `<BookDetails bookid={{bookid: 'id1'}} />` instead of `<BookDetails bookid="id1" />`

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of searching and reading to no avail, somebody thankfully commented on the original youtube video with the answer. Here is the working code for anybody who may come across this in the future;

```
import { useQuery } from '@apollo/client';
import { getBookQuery } from '../queries/queries'

const displayBookDetails = (loading, data, error) => {
    if (loading) return <p>loading...</p>
    if (error) return <p>Something went wrong..</p>
    if (data.book) {
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>{data.book.name}</h2>
                <p>{data.book.genre}</p>
                <p>{data.book.author.name}</p>
                <p>All the books by the author: </p>
                <ul className="other-books">
                    {data.book.author.books.map(item =>{
                        return<li key={item.id}>{item.name}</li>
                    })
                    }
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }else{
        return(
            <div>
                No data to display..
            </div>
        )
    }
}


function BookDetails(props) {
    const { loading, data, error } = useQuery(getBookQuery, {
        variables: {
            id: props.bookId
        }
    });
    // console.log(data)
    return (
        <div id="book-details">
            <p>OutPut here</p>
            {displayBookDetails(loading, data, error)}
        </div>
    )
}

export default BookDetails;
```